# Do i need Symfony2's $form->isValid() for a search field?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have created a **search form** on the fly in my controller to list users by nicknames / names:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('username', 'search', array('required'=> false))
        ->add('name', 'search', array('required'=> false))
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

So, because this form isn't mappped in my database, I don't use any Assert.

**My question** : I don't know if I have to use [isValid()](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_isValid) because I don't know if this method does the same as `get(‘validator’)->validate()`, (then I wouldn't need it), or if it checks other interresting things.

Thanks for help, have a nice day!

Comment: What is your aim, what do you want to do with this code, could you post the full action please?

Comment: Updated, sorry, I omitted the main part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is recommended, you can check in the good practice advices of symfony developpers :

They recommend using `$form->isSubmitted()` in the if statement for clarity. This isn't technically needed, since `isValid()` first calls `isSubmitted()`. But without this, the flow doesn't read well as it looks like the form is always processed (even on the `GET` request).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html